# How does bcc64.exe store debug information?

Tags: c++builder, debug-symbols, rad-studio

I am working on a debugger and now I need to support retrieving debug information from binaries made by bcc64.exe / ilink64.exe.

32-bit versions of bcc32.exe / ilink32.exe place debug information to TDS file, but bcc64.exe / ilink64.exe did not generate a TDS file.

It is definitely there is some storage for debug information because when I try to debug such executable from within RAD Studio it shows that the binary has debug information, a call stack shows correct entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64-bit version of BCB compiler, bcc64.exe, stores debug information in DWARF format.